# I want to add a trigger to my SQL such that it increments/decrements the counter according to insert/delete operations on the table itself

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mysql-workbench

The table that keeps track of records is RecordTable. It has two columns, RecordNumber of type INT and RecordType of type varchar(10). This table increments the value of RecordNumber each time a new row is added to it and decrements the value of RecordNumber each time a row is deleted from it.

However, when I do this, MySQL Workbench shows me two errors.
Both of them say:- "missing ';' ".

```
CREATE TRIGGER RecordTable_Insert AFTER INSERT ON RecordTable
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE RecordTable r set r.RecordNumber = r.RecordNumber + 1; //error here
    END; //error here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make RecordNumber as an auto increment column, and adjust to the fact that when you delete records and later do inserts, some numbers will be missed.